# Django Rest dynamically choose fields to render

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

In my models, I have `UserProfile` that has a field called `public_profile`. The serializer for `Event` model (another model) is:

```
class EventSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

  going = UserProfSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)
  notGoing = UserProfSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)

  class Meta:
    model = Event
    fields = ('name', 'place', 'date', 'going', 'notGoing', 'slug')
```

Where `going` and `notGoing` is a many-to-many relation in the database to UserProfile. My question is how I can select which fields to render in the UserProfSerializer depending on the profile configuration if it is public or not. For example, I want the user pk and profile picture to show but not the username.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could overwrite the `to_representation` method:

```
class UserProfSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    PUBLIC_FIELDS = ('id', 'avatar')

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'avatar')

    def to_representation(self, obj):
        response = super(UserProfSerializer, self).to_representation(obj)
        if not obj.public_profile:
            for field in response:
                if field not in self.PUBLIC_FIELDS:
                    del response[field]
        return response
```

Comment: Don't forget to up-vote the answer if you like it :]